# NgRx Singals - How to test signal store?

Tags: ngrx, angular-signals

I've been looking for information on how to test NgRX singalStore I use in my project. Unlike @ngrx/store, there is no documentation regarding testing ([store testing link](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing)).

With presented code:

```
export const store = signalStore(
  { providedIn: 'root' },
  withState(initialState),
  withComputed(() => ({
    // ...
  })),
  withMethods(state => {
    // ...
  }),
  withHooks({
    onInit() {
      // ...
    },
  }),
);
```

I'd like to know:

1. How to mock store initial state?
2. How to test withHooks part?

About 1.
I could potentially set state using my state methods, but this is not the best approach.
Also, I found out that you can make class-based signalStore in this [FAQ](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/076a76f6e734e3286bf7a0a1729da0a5295894bf/projects/ngrx.io/content/guide/signals/faq.md), so perhaps I can pass my mockedInitialState there.

Edit: After playing, I managed to wrap this signalStore into a function that gets initialState as an argument, defaulting to my desired initialState.

```
export const TaskStore = (state = initialState) =>
  signalStore(..)
```

About 2.
I can think of mocking a component, running ngOnInit in it then expecting state changes.

Do you guys have other ideas, or maybe working examples?

There is an open issue about missing testing docs [link](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/4206)